# More concise non-case-sensitive quiz verification

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, input

This question is a bit obscure and specific so I don't think I can find it anywhere, so...

I have 3 inputs in a 'quiz,' and was just wondering if there was anyway better way to do the following:

I am using an `If... Else...` statement to check the answers, and would like to make it **not** case sensitive

This is *(a stripped down version of)* my try... (please go easy on me I'm not particularly advanced and I know there are far better ways to achieve this but I would like to do it this sort of way...)

```
<input id="ans1">
<input id="ans2">
<input id="ans3">
```

### And the Javascript...

```
var ans1 = document.getElementById("ans1").value;
var ans2 = document.getElementById("ans2").value;
var ans3 = document.getElementById("ans3").value;
var ans1 = ans1.toLowerCase();
var ans2 = ans2.toLowerCase();
var ans3 = ans3.toLowerCase();

if (ans1 == "hola") {
   alert('Correct');
} else {
   alert('Incorrect');
  }
if (ans2 == "llamas") {
   alert('Correct');
} else {
   alert('Incorrect');
  }
if (ans3 == "me") {
   alert('Correct');
} else {
   alert('Incorrect');
  }}
```

So basically, I was just wondering if there were any more concise, or better way, of doing this?

Thanks, any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could use a function to reduce the repeated code:

```
function checkAnswer(id, correctResponse) {
  var answer = document.getElementById(id).value.toLowerCase();
  if(answer === correctResponse) {
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  }
}
checkAnswer("ans1", "hola");
checkAnswer("ans2", "llamas");
checkAnswer("ans3", "me");
```

You could also create an object associating the elements to the answers:

```
var correctAnswers = {
  "ans1": "hola",
  "ans2": "llamas",
  "ans3": "me"
};
for(var id in correctAnswers) {
  var answer = document.getElementById(id).value.toLowerCase();
  if(answer === correctAnswers[id]) {
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `Array`s?

```
var ids = [
    "ans1",
    "ans2",
    "ans3"
];
var answers = [
    "hola",
    "llamas",
    "me",
];
for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
    var user = elem.value;
    var answer = answers[i];
    if (answer == user.toLowerCase()) {
         alert('Correct');
    } else {
         alert('Incorrect');
    }
}
```